# The count of samples of a random variable before its sampled value gets greater than a threshold

Tags: random-variables

Say we have a random variable which follows Lognormal distribution. We take samples of this r.v. repeatedly, until the value of the sample is greater than a fixed threshold.

Can we find the mathematical expression of the count, and the summation of the values, of all taken samples before we stop?

Comment: Are you merely looking for notations to represent these two quantities? Or are you looking for information about their probability distributions?

Comment: Hi, David, my first goal is to find a mathematical expression of those two values without considering their probability distribution. I just ran a Matlab simulation and found both values fit Exponential distribution very well, so I am now wondering if I can eventually "prove" (or just solve), they fit Exponential distribution.